# CSS How to display an image in the size of a <span> / text line

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to show an image in the same place as a `<span>` , with same dimensions like the background of it, but in front of the text?
Hopefully the image explains it better:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
span {position:relative;}
span:after {content:""; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; height:100%; width:100%; background:url(http://www.transparenttextures.com/patterns/carbon-fibre-big.png);}
```

see fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/n0dgdxaL/

Note: if the span wraps to a second line, this won't work.  But it is fine for a single line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:before`, set his `position:absolute` and `z-index:1`. Of you will add your code I will show you how to do this..

To ensure that the size of the background of the `:before` element will fit, use [`background-size`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) property to `100%`.

Comment: Hey, I already found this trick, but in my case the result is bigger than the boundaries of the text (or smaller). How can I fit the text length?

Comment: I just was updated my answer.. Again, show me your code so I could show you exactly how to do this..

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have it: both of you were right.
The "position:relative" attribute in the span makes the image fit the text. Thank you!